# Syntax error / transformation error while using ES6 / tags in Express project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use a few named imports and JSX components in my node js project's `routes/index.js`, but I am getting below error:

1. `import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router';`

   Error:

   > Transformation error; return original code { Error: Line xx: Unexpected token `{`
2. `const server = (<StaticRouter location...);`

   Error:

   > Transformation error; return original code { Error: Line xx: Unexpected token `<`

Other Details:

- **node v8.11.***
- **express**
- **.babelrc**

  `{ "presets": [ "react", "es2015", "stage-3" ] }`
- **./index.js** has

  `require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
  });`
- **`node .`** to start the app, thats when I get these errors.

I don't have any problem with client side code, they are getting transpiled perfectly. Need help for above.

Comment: `import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router';` => `import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom";` i guess that will fix the first error .

Comment: What does your build command look like? (I.e how are you transpiling your server side JS?)

Comment: Hi ХристиянХристов, did not work. Hi Allen, added info at the bottom part.

Comment: Is `./index.js` the same as `routes/index.js`? From the documentation of [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/), it seems like adding that `require` transpiles future `require`s on the fly (so any ES6/JSX syntax in `./index.js` would not be converted in your case).

Comment: No, they are not the same. Babel require won't work seems. But while starting the app, I can't use babel-node anyways in production.

Answer (score 0):

add ["babel-plugin-import"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import). still in node.js we don't have import support.